# Why does the state in ReactjS vs firebase data not match?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning to use Firebase using reactJS. I am trying to update my `firebaseList` state to match the Firebase database.

```
...
const dbRef = firebase.initializeApp(config).database().ref().child('text');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      firebaseList: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    dbRef.on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      this.setState({
        firebaseList: snap.val()
      });
      console.log('firebaseList:  ', this.state.firebaseList);
    });
  }
...
```

When I go to chrome console after pushing a new string, `"This is a test!"`, this is displayed:

```
Object {-KeoiS8luCsuKhzc_Eut: "asdf", -Keol-2Si05dmkmuac8l: "This is a test!"}
firebaseList:   Object {-KeoiS8luCsuKhzc_Eut: "asdf"}
```

Why is my `firebaseList` state behind by one element? Why does `snap.val()` have two key-value pairs and `firebaseList` only has one key-value pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, because they can be processed in batches. This means that although you call `console.log` in your code after your `setState`, the state may not have actually changed yet.

From the React docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you would like to check if your state is updated, you can either used a callback as the second argument to `setState` or put some logic in the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` lifecycle method.

Example:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    dbRef.on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      this.setState({
        firebaseList: snap.val()
      }, () => console.log('firebaseList:  ', this.state.firebaseList))
    });
  }
```

or

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.state.firebaseList !== nextState.firebaseList) {
    console.log('firebaseList:  ', nextState.firebaseList);
  }
}
```

**setState Documentation:** (Note the function signature, `setState(nextState, callback)`)

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

**shouldComponentUpdate Documentation:**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate